# Rational rose comment block

Tags: uml, doxygen, ibm-rational, rational-rose

This question might be a bit off topic, but I'm stuck with a comment block.

In the doxygen documentation code there is the comment type `/##Documentation` mentioned with comment `Start of Rational Rose ANSI C++ comment block`.
It looks like that a comment block can be continued by means of `///` comments but only when it starts at the same column.

I tried to find some documentation about the syntax of this type of comment.

Question is: what is the syntax of the `/##Documentation` and when is it terminated.